# CRM2011 Filtered Views and Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm

I have a strange problem, I am trying to use reports within dynamics, I have created a query that runs agains the Filtered Views:

```sql
SELECT TOP 10 Activity.ActivityOn, Activity.Name, Activity.activitytypecodename, Activity.subject, Activity.owneridname, Activity.createdon FROM (
SELECT 'Project' as ActivityOn, project.new_name AS Name, activitytypecodename, subject, activity.description, activity.owneridname, activity.createdon FROM dbo.Filterednew_project project
JOIN dbo.FilteredActivityPointer activity on project.new_projectid = activity.regardingobjectid
WHERE project.new_projectid = @ProjectId AND (NOT activity.statecode = 2)) Activity ORDER BY Activity.createdon DESC
```

However when I try to run the report that uses this in Dynamics, no rows are returned (I am logged in as myself, with full sys admin privilages.)  Yet, when I run it on SSRS (through /reports) then it returns rows.  (this is also running as myself.)

Does anyone have any ideas of what is wrong?  (There are no errors, it just fails to return data in dynamics.)

Comment: The filtered views use the login user's roles and rights to determine what should be returned.  My guess is that when you are running it in Dynamics, it is actually running under a different account...

Comment: Is there an easy way to find out who it is being run as?

Comment: I wonder if something could be wrong with the SSRS service account. Does any other custom SSRS in Dynamics CRM return any data?